# How do I display and store a PDF file from webservice? Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How do I display and store a PDF file from webservice? In Android and Ios
I got base64binary from web services
Then I stored it in a byte

**I don't know what is the next step**
**can i use this?
Xamarin.Essentials**

This is Cody:

string base64BinaryStr = await vm.DownloadETransAttFile(itemSelected.ATTCH_ID, itemSelected.ATTCH_VERSION, itemSelected.ATTCH_KND);
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);

```
       // Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker.PickAsync....!!!!!
```

Comment: You could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)  to save the file on each platform,and then return the filepath to display it.You could refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74519/convert-byte-array-to-pdf-for-android-and-ios-in-xamarin-forms.

Comment: You can decode the base64 string using [System.Convert.FromBase64()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-5.0). For display, the LEADTOOLS [Xamarin SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/xamarin) has a Xamarin.Forms .NET Document Viewer that can be used to display the PDF on both Android and iOS (Disclaimer:  I work for the vendor). As for storage, since you have the data decoded, you can create the PDF file directly using [System.IO.FileStream.Write()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.write?view=net-5.0).